# When I can't short CS to ground using only one SPI device?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, microchip

Last time I was writing an easy program for some old processor to interface with MCP3004 (Microchip's ADC with SPI interface). Processor had no hardware SPI implementation so I had to write it on my own.

To my surprise program didn't work until I changed the code to toggle CS down-up-down with some delay each time I am communicating with ADC.
Always before I was sure that ChipSelect can and even should (to reduce amount of used pins) be physically shorted to ground when I use only one device.

Is there any explanation why that time it didn't worked: when I can't short CS to the ground when I am using only one SPI device?

Comment: (a) You said: "*program didn't work **as long as** I changed the code to toggle CS*" [my bold]. I think you probably mean "*program didn't work **until** I changed the code to toggle CS*". Is that what you meant? As currently written, it is ambiguous. Please clarify. (b) As stated in the duplicate question, you need to follow the device's datasheet (e.g. it's clear in the MCP3004 datasheet). (c) I see you haven't accepted any answers to your previous questions, even when they seem good and you didn't ask for clarification. Please read the site [tour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rising/falling CS line is not only used to enable the output of the slave, but also to reset its internal state machine. For example some flash memories have a following sequence to read: `command_opcode address_byte1 address_byte2` and dummy bytes. You send as many dummy bytes as you want, the address within the slave is automatically incremented. How would you be able to send another command (eg. write) if there was no way to end the transaction? The CS line does exactly that.